# VS message: wait for a request without enabling ASP.NET debugging

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-debugging

In my Visual Studio 2010 Solution with a WCF Service Project, I have my `Web` settings to `Use Visual Studio Development Server` and `Don't open a page. Wait for a request from an external application.`. Every time I start the project without debugging, Visual Studio comes up with the following message:

> Choosing to wait for a request from another process without enabling
>   ASP.NET debugging results in nothing to debug.

I am aware of this. It is OK, however, as I am using the service from my Windows Forms application that is started as well. Any ideas how to turn that message off?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this is more than a little late, but thought I'd add this answer as this question ranks highly when searching for the message text:

> Choosing to wait for a request from another process without enabling
>   ASP.NET debugging results in nothing to debug.

It appears Microsoft have confirmed there is no fix for this for Visual Studio 2010, but has been fixed for the next version of Visual Studio.

Source: [Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/695193/message-prompt-with-start-without-debugging-on-mvc-3-projects)

Comment: Thank you, Steve! The message is still annoying me, so it's good to know it's going to be fixed...

Answer (score 0):

You can enable ASP.NET Debugging by checking off ASP.NET in your project properties - Web - Debuggers (bottom of the page). That fixes this issue for me.