# How to remove visual studio's popup "Choosing to wait for a request..."

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, debugging

I have a project that has, amongst other things, one web application (mvc) and one WPF application. For the part that matters, the WPF app connect to a WCF service hosted on the website.

What I want to achieve is that when I press Ctrl+F5 (start WITHOUT debugging), the build process kicks in (if needed, in other words, the default VS behavior), the WPF app launched, and if the webdev server is not launched, that it get launched too, but without opening any page on my browser (I'll manage that myself).

I managed to get that working as I want (configuration below), but every time I do a Ctrl+F5, I get a popup from VS that says

> Choosing to wait for a request from another process without enabling
>   ASP.NET debugging results in nothing to debug.

I value the information, and that seems to match pretty much what I'm trying to accomplish anyway, but now, instead of having to close a useless tab in my browser, I have to close a modal dialog. Not a big improvement from my point of view.

So, how do I prevent this popup to show up ?

Additional information:

- I don't want to start in debug mode (F5). If I need debug for the website, I'll do my usual (attaching to the webdev server).
- I want the webdev server to be running all the time from the first CTRL+F5.
- I don't want to publish it on IIS (even the express version)
- The solution startup option is set on "Multi startup project" with the WPF app on "Start" and the website on "Start without debugging" (setting it on Start doesn't change anything, except that I also get the popup when debugging with F5 directly).
- The website has its start action configured on "Don't open a page. Wait for a request from an external application". The ASP.NET checkbox in the Debuggers is checked.

Internet had not been a big help so far, so all my hopes lies on you SOers !

**Edit**

It seems that it was [flagged as a bug](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/695193/message-prompt-with-start-without-debugging-on-mvc-3-projects), but I don't see any reference in what version it's supposed to be fixed...

Also, I discovered my question is a [duplicate of this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8033733/vs-message-wait-for-a-request-without-enabling-asp-net-debugging).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually found another way : in the start actions, you can set it to "start external program" and reference a self quitting program. I used "C:\Windows\System32\PING.EXE". Not perfect, but also less annoying than the previous solutions.